# What is the reason that C++11 gives up auto_ptr?

Tags: c++, c++11, smart-pointers

It gives up `auto_ptr`  and adds `unique_ptr` and `shared_ptr`.  Are they good enough to let c++ abandon `auto_ptr`? There must be sometimes `auto_ptr` could lead to bad results. Can anyone give me an example?

If it doesn't do bad C++11 will keep it rather than give up.

Comment: In addition to the other answers, which are all good, using `unique_ptr` and `shared_ptr` via `make_unique` or `make_shared` is much more effective than using the vanilla `auto_ptr` constructor with a `new` operator inside it.

Comment: Make note of 'guru question #4': http://herbsutter.com/2013/05/29/gotw-89-solution-smart-pointers/

Answer (score 4):

Because `unique_ptr` is a better alternative for `auto_ptr`.

In particular, it was not possible to store an `auto_ptr` in a container. While you can store `unique_ptr` in a container.

Comment: Actually there's no problem returning an `auto_ptr` from a function. That's one of the only things it's good at.

Comment: @MarkRansom You are right, corrected. It makes sense as it transfers the ownership, I must have bad memory about its usage.

Answer (score 4):

auto_ptr was copy constructible which used to move the ownership, e.g.,

```
    auto_ptr a;
    ....
    auto_ptr<int> b = a; // a loses its ownership here
```

This can lead to confusion and bugs.

unique_ptr is not copy constructible. It is move constructible which moves the ownership, e.g.,

```
    unique_ptr a;
    ....
    unique_ptr<int> b = a; // ERROR, wont compile

    unique_ptr<int> b = std::move(a); // OK, as programmer is explicitly moving ownership, no confusion

    unique_ptr<int> b = unique_ptr(p); // OK, ownership will move from temporary unique_ptr
```

shared_ptr is obviously to share ownership, so:

```
    shared_ptr a;
    ...
    shared_ptr b = a; // both a and b have ownership, underlying pointer will only be freed when a and b both are out of scope
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `auto_ptr` leads to bad results.

If you assign one `auto_ptr` to another, the first pointer loses its pointer altogether. This is a surprising result that leads to bugs.

```
auto_ptr<int> p1(new int(42));
auto_ptr<int> p2 = p1;        // at this point p1 is a bad pointer
```

`unique_ptr` is a much better alternative.

Comment: Agreed. Just adding that unique_ptr's solution is to make the transfer of ownership *explicit* and compile-time checked.

Answer (score 1):

The C++ Standard says that an STL element must be "copy-constructible" and "assignable."  An element must be able to be assigned or copied and the two elements are logically independent. std::auto_ptr does not fulfill this requirement. In other words,the STL containers need to be able to copy the items you store in them, and are designed to expect the original and the copy to be equivalent. Auto pointer objects have a completely different contract, whereby copying creates a transfer of ownership. This means that containers of auto_ptr will exhibit strange behaviour, depending on usage.

unique_ptr is really the direct auto_ptr replacement, it combines the best features of both std::auto_ptr and boost::scoped_ptr.